# phpmyadmin using mysqli connects, but my php using mysqli errors out

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, mysqli

This is driving me nuts!  I am getting the classic "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql4d/mysql4d.sock' (13)".

Everything I've dug up so far tells me my setup should be OK (eg, defining the sockets in php.ini and my.cnf, etc).  Worse... phpmyadmin works with the same un/pw I am using in my own php.  So obviously it's possible to connect, but I am screwing it up

I tried reverse-engineering the connection from phpmyadmin, but gave up it as too convoluted after a couple hours.

Can anyone offer some advice?

My configuration: Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic), Apache 2.2, PHP 5.2.6, MySQL 4.1.22 (for legacy app reasons).

my.cnf (/var/lib/mysql4/my.cnf):

> [client]
>       port            = 3306
>       socket          = /var/run/mysql4d/mysql4d.sock
>       [mysqld]
>       port            = 3306
>       socket          = /var/run/mysql4d/mysql4d.sock

php.ini (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini):

> [MySQL]
>       mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysql4d/mysql4d.sock
>       [MySQLi]
>       mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysql4d/mysql4d.sock

Same problem using mysql instead of mysqli, btw.

EDIT:
I should mention that I have installed mysql4 alongside the ubuntu default install of php & mysql for use with a legacy application and it is this installation that I am having trouble connecting with.  I tried this:

> ini_set('mysql.default_socket', '/var/run/mysql4d/mysql4d.sock');

and now the connection goes thru, but all queries return empty sets. (cries in frustration)

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't error 13 "Permission denied"? Could it be that you don't have permission to access the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a permission problem in `/var/run/mysql4d/mysql4d.sock`. What user are you running this as? Are the permissions o.k. on file system level?

If you Google for the error messages, you'll find a lot of people who had this and it was always a permission issue, sometimes due to an activated [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux). Check [this thread](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/2002-can-t-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-14130.html) for a few possible solutions.

Comment: Hey Pekka, thanks for the tip!  But I don't have selinux installed on my machine.  Nothing on the thread was helpful, alas.

If it is a permissions issue, tho, perhaps my apache.conf is badly written...

Comment: Hmm, too bad! Does the socket actually exist? Have you checked its permissions? Is the Apache user allowed to access it?

Comment: Yup, socket exists:  srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql4 mysql4 0 2010-01-01 14:15 /var/run/mysql4d/mysql4d.sock      Apache must be allowed to access it, or phpmyadmin wouldn't work.

Comment: All right. Is it an option to bypass the socket? If it is, try connecting to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost (see "Notes" in http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php why). Maybe that helps. I'm off now till tomorrow. Good luck!

Comment: Aha! I tried overriding to use tcp/ip with mysqli instead of mysql, and it suddenly started working!  mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', $un, $pw, $db, 3306);  It *doesn't* work with mysql_connect (which is hilarious, as the docs mention it on the mysql_connect page but not mysqli_connect).  Thanks for all your help, Pekka!